# Phaser JS: How to move an object in a static group

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Okay, I have a problem, I have an object which I don't want to respond with the typical physics rule, but which I'd like the player to be able to move on a set track.

It's part of a staticGroup, which appears to take it out of the physics engine.

I've written this method which makes the moves I'd like it to make:

```
slider.setY(slider.y - block_size);
```

BUT

This moves the sprite on screen, but not the object which the user collides with. The user can keep colliding with it's initial location, which makes moving it meaningless. I want to be able to change the location of the physical object, as well as the visible one.

What am I doing wrong, here?

Comment: Is it moving in only one direction??? 
are there two separate objects i.e. Physical and visible one?

Comment: Well, there's two directions it can move. Because the collision event is in the same place after moving the image, I assume they're two objects.

Comment: So you need to maintain direction variable as to make it move on different different direction.

Comment: @spankajd I think, perhaps, that my example contains more code than it needs to, and that's muddying the waters. I'll tidy it up.